# Texture/Material to a Prefab in Unity 3D Not Working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have converted an `.obj` file to `.fbx` file. I then imported it in a Mesh folder, created a Prefab out of it. It has a material assigned to it as well i.e. automatically created in a local Materials folder (No Name). When I try to change the Texture of that Material, Nothing happens. If I change the Material color  then I can see the changed color of the Prefab on the Scene View but no texture.

Is there any problem with my `.fbx` file ?

** I am doing this all in Unity software in inspector window, not in a scripting language.

Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Can you show some code? Is the same thing happening if you try with an instantiated object instead of a prefab?

Comment: What shader are you using?

Comment: I didn't do it with the UnityC# code though I want to eventually. But currently I tried it in the Unity(4.3.4) Software using the inspector. I have tried almost all the shader options available in the inspector. But currently it is set to Custom/brightTexture.
Thank you